# How to print binary numbers digit by digit in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a binary number in javascript:

```
var myNumber = 0b0001110;
```

How do I print it digit by digit? It would output this:

```
0
0
0
1
1
1
0
```

I tried to console `String(myNumber).charAt(n)` , with n being a given position, but it didn't work, also I don't want it to be converted to string. I want the decimal digits 0 and 1.
I'm asking for a way to print the numbers, but my ultimate goal here is to have access to them.

Comment: `(0b0001110).toString(2).split("")` - you will need to add the leading cosmetic 0s yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert the number to a string and then loop over the characters:

```js
var myNumber = 0b0001110;
var myString = myNumber.toString(2);

for(var x = 0; x < myString .length; x++){
  console.log(myString [x]);
}
```